# In Ember 2.0 component factories must have an `isComponentFactory` property set to true

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm getting this deprecation warning when using a component which extends Ember.Checkbox:

```
In Ember 2.0 component factories must have an `isComponentFactory` property set to true. You registered (subclass of Ember.Checkbox) as a component factory. Either add the `isComponentFactory` property to this factory or extend from Ember.Component.
```

I would appreciate a good explanation of the logic behind this.

Comment: What ember version are you currently using ? Struggling to reproduce this in a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/68844b9355507a252d847d1ce4e34f78?openFiles=components.ext-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.ext-component.hbs), maybe you can adjust it to fit your use case ?

Comment: I'm on Ember 1.13.10, but I assume it would be same in 2.x?

Comment: I am guessing it's because factories by default create singletons, and components aren't singletons so you need some way to indicate that to Ember's container.

Comment: I've switched that twiddle between multiple versions now, and get the same deprecation in 1.13.13, the moment you go up to 2.1,2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 your component works as expected, without any issues. So to be honest, I would recommend forgetting about it and moving on for now.

Comment: Why would you even extend from `Ember.Checkbox`? You would need to struggle with a lot of private APIs if you want to do something useful with it.